# Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

**So i have a problem when adding this line

> id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

into plugins in app gradle

**

```
    Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
DefaultTaskContainer#NamedDomainObjectProvider.configure(Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
DefaultTaskContainer#NamedDomainObjectProvider.configure(Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:259)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:120)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:104)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:398)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:368)
```

**now is this line necessary for firebase with android
becuase i think if i delete this line maybe problems happens in code i hope you guys understand me  **

**all this problem hapen when i add the firebase cloud messaging but i have found that this is not the problem the problem was only in that line **

*

> id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

- 

Comment: Check your gradle and playservices and firbase dependency. I this all not collaborate  each other.

Comment: Can you make it more clear please?

Comment: Do you mean make all firebase dependency has the same version

Comment: It's dependencies issue change firebasr, Gradle play services which each other suitable. Try use firebase Bom for firebase dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes I am experiencing the same problem

but you can try changing

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
```

in the app level gradle file

and see if that works

Comment: Hi Ishaan and welcome on SO!
Another workaround that works for me is to disable `mappingFileUploadEnabled` by setting it to `false`. This has the disadvantage of the stack traces being obfuscated…

Answer (score 0):

A small update on this: with version `4.3.10`, this [bug](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/197) was [fixed](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/commit/56c2c5609ee5d1ee9e3cd925a08f31ab4ecd3372).

So you can change the version of `com.google.gms:google-services` to `4.3.10`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while implementing the ML kit in React native project.

Let me share with you the way how I fixed this:
I changed my **classpath** in **project => android => build.gradle** file

from

**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'**

to

**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'**

Also, my applicationID was commented mistakenly in **project => android => app => build.gradle** file. See if you have similar unwanted human errors.
Happy to help!